# Error while creating android AVD: (Permission denied) inside Ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools

I am beginner to program apps IOS and Android.

I have **Eclipse** with **Android SDK** and **AVD** inside **Ubuntu**.

When I launch `android` from the terminal. This call `Android SDK Manager`

I open this question because the problem is when I create the device AVD.
I installed two version of Android:

```
user@user-F50Sf:~/Downloads$ android list targets
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-18"
     Name: Android 4.3
     Type: Platform
     API level: 18
     Revision: 2
     Skins: WXGA800, WXGA800-7in, WSVGA, WQVGA400, HVGA, WXGA720, WVGA800 (default), QVGA, WQVGA432, WVGA854
     ABIs : no ABIs.
----------
id: 2 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 2
     Skins: WXGA800, WXGA800-7in, WSVGA, WQVGA400, HVGA, WXGA720, WVGA800 (default), QVGA, WQVGA432, WVGA854
     ABIs : armeabi-v7a
user@user-F50Sf:~/Downloads$
```

[image: Android SDK]Now I want to create the new device from terminal and I have this error:

```
 user@user-F50Sf:~/Downloads$ android create avd -n mySim -t android-19
    Auto-selecting single ABI armeabi-v7a
    Android 4.4.2 is a basic Android platform.
    Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]
    Error: /home/user/.android/avd/mySim.ini (Permission denied)
```

This error I have also inside Eclipse always when I create new device AVD
[image: Image of error eclipse]

I try to add the path of Phonepag inside the `/etc/profile`, after I update it.
But the terminal gets still the error

**/etc/profile**

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

# The default umask is now handled by pam_umask.
# See pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs.

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/bin
```

Where I wrong???

***EDIT:***
Using **sudo** I have *command not found*

```
sudo android create avd -n mySim -t android-19
[sudo] password for user: 
sudo: android: command not found
```

Comment: what happens when you run it as sudo (not sure which directories its writing to)

Comment: ´sudo android create avd -n mySim -t android-19
[sudo] password for user: 
sudo: android: command not found´

Comment: android is not located in the system path. You need to gogo into the directory where the file android is found then repeat the command bbut with ./android not android. 

 sudo android create avd -n mySim -t
android-19

If that works, then it's a permission things and you change the permissions of that folder recursively.

Sudo chmod 777 folder -r

Comment: now function using sudo -s chmod -R 777 /home/user/.android/

Comment: why now I have this error after that I create AVD 

user@user-F50Sf:~$ emulator -avd mySim
NAND: could not write file /home/user/.android/avd/mySim.avd/userdata-qemu.img, No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

The AVD Manager can't acess the .android folder.
Not sure if its the right solution, but changing the permission of the folder worked for me:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /home/user/.android
```

The "user" here is the user which is executing the AVD Manager, most probably your user.

Comment: To add to this, there were several places where my permissions were off. First, I installed the android-tools-adb package in Ubuntu and had to run it as root, so when it created the .android directory in my home director (~/.android), it created it as root.

Second, when I did ```./configure; make; make install``` for android studio, I also used ```sudo```, so I had to change those director permissions, too (though I'm not convinced this was crucial -- I'm just not willing to go back and test without changing them.)